# Wake up react native app to obtain fcm token

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

We recently integrated firebase to out react native apps on android and ios for push notifications using `react-native-firebase`. Since we do not currently have the fcm tokens and we can only obtain them once a user opens the app once again. Is there a way to send notifications to all the users or to schedule a local notification using `react-native-firebase` without the user opening the app so that we can obtain the fcm token for the device.